# Import custom component in React with react-select and crash with Error: Minified React error #188

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-select

I develop a custom library of components in React(16.4) and Webpack 4. Config was eject and import to other project with git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org.... on package.json.

Only one component doesn't work when I used this lib in other project,  it's a select input develop with react-select (Jed Watson) and it crashes on click.

All app crashes and I have this error:

> Uncaught Error: Minified React error #188; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=188 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.

Message from link in error above:

> Unable to find node on an unmounted component.

I now my problem is with my webpack config but I don't find any solutions to fix this.

Last hope with community...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation - I am developing a custom component library and importing it into an external project. I had issues with react-bootstrap, react-transition-group, and other external libraries that dynamically mount/unmount DOM elements in production; minified react error #188 would crash production builds. Here's how I solved it in our webpack config under module.exports (both dev and prod configs):

```
alias: {
  // Support React Native Web
  // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
  "react-native": "react-native-web",
  react: path.resolve("./node_modules/react"),
  "react-dom": path.resolve("./node_modules/react-dom"),
  "react-transition-group": path.resolve(
    "./node_modules/react-transition-group"
  )
}
```

This should override any other instances of these particular libraries in all dependencies; anytime they're imported/used, they're forced to use the version that my project dictates in the package.json. Please keep in mind that I'm using Webpack 3, so the fix for Webpack 4 may be different.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Abi.

I've just resolve it with other way. I add all library in "externals" in my webpack config like this :

```
externals: [
  'react-select': {
     root: 'ReactSelect',
     commonjs2: 'react-select',
     commonjs: 'react-select',
     amd: 'react-select',
  },
]
```